# How to delay start Angular application to show animation

Tags: angular

I've added some loading animation to my Angular application between `<app-root> HERE </app-root>` tag.

I need to delay start to show and check this animation. I know about JS `setTimeout()` but where to possibly place it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few days back I applied a loader in my project. Here is how I achieved it.

**Step 1**

Import your loader in the main.module.ts file and add it to your imports array. I used [NgxSpinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner). Its pretty easy and comes with some very good loader.

```
//Importing Loader
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
```

**Step 2**

Import the module again in the .ts file of the component where you want to use it and initialize it in the constructor().

**Step 3**

Add a `show()` class before subscribing to the observable, and then add a `setTimeout()` function to hide the spinner/loader in given time.

Here is the snippet from my project.

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log("ngOnInit called");

    // getting the name of the book from the route
    let myBookName = this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name');
    console.log(myBookName);

    this.spinner.show();


    this.bookHttpService.getSingleBookInfo(myBookName).subscribe(

      data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.currentBook = data;
      },
      error => {
        console.log("some error occured");
        console.log(error.errorMessage);
      }
    )
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.spinner.hide();
    }, 2000);
  }
```

> Keep in mind that you will also have to [delay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/delay.html) your response to
>   achieve a smooth effect.

**UPDATE**

Also, put the loader at the top of the template file of that paticular view.

Comment: It's loading animation inside application. I asked about situation when somebody first time open my website. I would show some loading animation before whole app is loaded 100%

Comment: Just import it into your main component and include it in your template and in ngOnInt().

Answer (score 3):

I think using the `APP_INITIALIZER` is the proper way to delay the app startup.

With `APP_INITIALIZER` you can easily add a delay by initializing the property `useValue` with a lambda that returns a `promise` which executes the `setTimeout()` function. To do this you should include the `APP_INITIALIZER` in the `providers` list of `@NgModule`. The below example creates a delay of 5 seconds.

```
import { APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
       {
         provide: APP_INITIALIZER, 
         useValue: () =>  new Promise(resolve =>
           setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
         ),
         multi: true
       }
    ]
    })
```

This will cause the content between `<app-root></app-root>` to be displayed for 5 seconds long.

Answer (score 1):

Organize your loader as plain html/css and put it inside `<app-root> HERE </app-root>`. It will be the first thing that will popup to the user. When app finishes initialization it replaces content of app root with application root component (effectively removing your preloader)

Comment: But what if you want to delay the beginning of the app? Sometimes the loading happens so quickly that you get a flash of light, which looks really ugly. I'd like to ensure that my app always waits before starting, no matter what.

Comment: You can artificially delay app bootstrap using app initializer.

Comment: @Magnus see my answer